# bouncy castle: How to get bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar with debug information

Tags: jar, bouncycastle, jce

I am trying to debug an issue with bouncy castle 1.47. I can find a debug jar for 'bcprov' but not for {org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.47:jar}.

Is there any other place to download bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar with debug information?

or

Is there a tool that can generate line numbers from a jar (containing .class files) without line numbers and also generated sources for the same generated jar?

or

I had been trying to build the jars from source [1](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) but the build cannot find the test jars I suppose from the errors.

```
  [javadoc] /tickets/bouncycastle/src-cvs/java/crypto/build/artifacts/jdk1.5/bcprov-jdk15on-147/src/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/AllTests.java:5: package junit.framework does not exist
  [javadoc] import junit.framework.Test;
  [javadoc]                       ^
  [javadoc] /tickets/bouncycastle/src-cvs/java/crypto/build/artifacts/jdk1.5/bcprov-jdk15on-147/src/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/AllTests.java:6: package junit.framework does not exist
  [javadoc] import junit.framework.TestCase;
  [javadoc]                       ^
  [javadoc] /tickets/bouncycastle/src-cvs/java/crypto/build/artifacts/jdk1.5/bcprov-jdk15on-147/src/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/AllTests.java:7: package junit.framework does not exist
  [javadoc] import junit.framework.TestSuite;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have managed to generate jar with debug information from bouncy castle source.

in ROOT_SRC/bc-build.properties, set release.debug to true

```
release.suffix: 147
release.name: 1.47
release.debug: true
```

The build expects mail (sun implementation) and junit jars to be available in classpath. I have put them on to jdk/jre/lib/ext and the build worked. the artifacts were generated in the ROOT_SRC/build directory.

Comment: I had to add the Gradle Wrapper. And the repo now already contains the dependencies listed above. But otherwise, the experience was the same - easy to build your debug copy. Thanks Rag!

Comment: Nicely worked. I just had to set debug=true and

```
export JDKPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto
bash build1-8+
```
and got the files in `build/artifacts/jdk1.8/jars`

Answer (score 9):

Instead of rolling your own build, you could exclude `bcprov-jdk15on` and explicitly pull in the debug-built `bcprov-debug-jdk15on` artifact.

Maven config example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-debug-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will allow you to debug bouncycastle stuff.

Comment: Does it enable to debug bcpkix-jdk15on as the OP is asking?.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel This depends. My case was that while my app depended on bcpkix, the actual part I needed to debug was from bcprov on which bcpkix depended on. So for me - it helped. I didn't need to swap out bcpkix, only bcprov and I could do my debugging.